# Android ListView's divider attribute hides inner ImageView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, hide, divider

I am trying to figure out a way to hide a ListView's divider. Normally, I would set 'android:divider="@color/transparent' but for whatever reason, this hides an ImageView (arrow) in the listitem layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/ListItem.Container" >
  <LinearLayout style="@style/ListContainer" android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView style="@style/ListItem.Title" />
    <TextView style="@style/ListItem.Date" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <FrameLayout style="@style/ListContainer">
    <TextView style="@style/ListItem.Details" />
  </FrameLayout>

  <FrameLayout style="@style/ListContainer">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arrow" style="@style/ListItem.Arrow" />
  </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//You can do in xml as `android:divider="@null"`

or

// you can also do it thru code as `listView.setDivider(null);`